# Ограничить максимальное число параллельных запросов

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

Имеется следующая функция:

```
export function getImage(requestParameters: MapLibreRequestParameters): MapLibreRequest<MapLibreResponse<ImageBitmap | HTMLImageElement>> {
    const request = helper.getArrayBuffer(requestParameters);

    return {
        response: (async () => {
            const response = await request.response;
            const image = await arrayBufferToCanvasImageSource(response.data);

            return {
                data: image,
                cacheControl: response.cacheControl,
                expires: response.expires
            };
        })(),

        cancel: request.cancel
    };
}
```

Она синхронная, но возвращает объект, состоящий из двух полей: `response` - `Promise`, который резолвится объектом (3 поля: `data, cacheControl, expires`, но это для нас неважно) и `cancel` - метод, который отменяет запрос.

Эта функция работает как нужно и все с ней хорошо. Однако, мне нужно реализовать дополнительное ограничение. **Нужно сделать** так, чтобы количество параллельных (одновременных) запросов к сети в любой момент времени не превышало `n`.

Таким образом, если `n === 0`, не должно быть сделано ни одного запроса. Если `n === 1`, то одновременно может загружаться только одно изображение (то есть все изображения загружаются последовательно). При `n > 1 < m` одновременно загружаться могут не более `m` изображений.

---

### Мое решение

Исходя из того что функция `getImage` синхронная, то строка

```
const request = helper.getArrayBuffer(requestParameters);
```

выполняется сразу же при вызове `getImage`. Такое нам не нужно, нам нужно выполнение самого запроса отложить. Поэтому переменную `request` заменим на функцию `requestMaker`, которую будем вызывать только тогда, когда нам это нужно:

```
export function getImage(requestParameters: MapLibreRequestParameters): MapLibreRequest<MapLibreResponse<ImageBitmap | HTMLImageElement>> {
    if (webpSupported.supported) {
        if (!requestParameters.headers) requestParameters.headers = {};
        requestParameters.headers['Accept'] = 'image/webp,*/*';
    }

    function requestMaker() {
        const request = helper.getArrayBuffer(requestParameters);
        return request;
    }

    return {
        response: (async () => {
            const response = await requestMaker().response;
            const image = await arrayBufferToCanvasImageSource(response.data);

            return {
                data: image,
                cacheControl: response.cacheControl,
                expires: response.expires
            };
        })(),

        cancel() {
            //
        }
    };
}
```

(`cancel` пока опустим).

Теперь выполнение этой функции `requestMaker`, делающей сам запрос, нужно отложить до какого-то момента.

Предположим, что сейчас мы пытаемся решить задачу только для `n === 1`.

Создадим массив, в котором будем хранить все запросы, выполняющиеся в данных момент:

```
const ongoingImageRequests = [];
```

Теперь внутри `requestMaker` будем сохранять в эту переменную запросы как только они происходят, и удалять их как только мы получаем ответ:

```
const ongoingImageRequests = [];

export function getImage(requestParameters: MapLibreRequestParameters): MapLibreRequest<MapLibreResponse<ImageBitmap | HTMLImageElement>> {
    if (webpSupported.supported) {
        if (!requestParameters.headers) requestParameters.headers = {};
        requestParameters.headers['Accept'] = 'image/webp,*/*';
    }

    function requestMaker() {
        const request = helper.getArrayBuffer(requestParameters);

        ongoingImageRequests.push(request);
        request.response.finally(() => ongoingImageRequests.splice(ongoingImageRequests.indexOf(request), 1));

        return request;
    }

    return {
        response: (async () => {
            const response = await requestMaker().response;
            const image = await arrayBufferToCanvasImageSource(response.data);

            return {
                data: image,
                cacheControl: response.cacheControl,
                expires: response.expires
            };
        })(),

        cancel() {
            //
        }
    };
}
```

Осталось лишь добавить ограничение касательно запуска `requestMaker`: перед тем как запустить ее, нужно дождаться `await` выполнения всех запросов из массива:

```
const ongoingImageRequests = [];

export function getImage(requestParameters: MapLibreRequestParameters): MapLibreRequest<MapLibreResponse<ImageBitmap | HTMLImageElement>> {
    if (webpSupported.supported) {
        if (!requestParameters.headers) requestParameters.headers = {};
        requestParameters.headers['Accept'] = 'image/webp,*/*';
    }

    function requestMaker() {
        const request = helper.getArrayBuffer(requestParameters);

        ongoingImageRequests.push(request);
        request.response.finally(() => ongoingImageRequests.splice(ongoingImageRequests.indexOf(request), 1));

        return request;
    }

    return {
        response: (async () => {
            await Promise.allSettled(ongoingImageRequests.map(ongoingImageRequest => ongoingImageRequest.response));

            const response = await requestMaker().response;
            const image = await arrayBufferToCanvasImageSource(response.data);

            return {
                data: image,
                cacheControl: response.cacheControl,
                expires: response.expires
            };
        })(),

        cancel() {
            //
        }
    };
}
```

Я понимаю это так: при начале выполнения `getImage` (она вызвана откуда-то извне), она сразу же возвращает объект, в котором `response` - это `Promise`, который разрешится как минимум не раньше того момента, когда будут выполнены все остальные запросы из очереди.

Но, как выходит, такое решение почему-то не работает. **Вопрос** - почему? И как сделать так, чтобы оно работало? Хотя бы для `n === 1`.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-queue

Comment: @nörbörnën не уверен, что использование сторонних библиотек допустимо в моем случае. Но все равно спасибо за наводку.